# Rails 5 ActionMailer sends mail, but not received in inbox

Tags: email, actionmailer, ruby-on-rails-5

I have spent considerable time and research (reading related posts in Stack Overflow) in an attempt to get a simple Rails 5 application to send an email. I have studied and followed the information found here: [Ruby on Rails Guides Action Mailer Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#example-action-mailer-configuration)

I am wondering if perhaps there is something important missing from the guide. Would someone mind creating a simple application as per the guide and tell me whether or not it works?

Here is the code I created following the Rails Guide (link shown above) in GitHub https://github.com/allenroulston/testmailer. When I was testing I was using an actual username and password. Looked like it should work, as per logs, but was not working. Does it work for you?

Answer (score 0):

**Your app/config/environment/development.rb**

```
config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            'youremail@gmail.com',
  password:             'YourGmailPassword',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true
}
config.file_watcher = ActiveSupport::EventedFileUpdateChecker
config.exceptions_app = self.routes
```

**in your user_mailer.rb**

```
class UserMailer < ApplicationMailer
default from: 'myemail@example.com'

def welcome_email(user)
    @user = user
    @url  = 'http://www.example.com'
    mail(to: @user.email, subject: 'Welcome to Example.com')
end
end
```

**This works perfectly**

Comment: When I follow the instructions shown at [Send Email using Rails](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/ruby-on-rails/rails-send-email.htm)
I encounter an error when I issue the following from the command line:
**rails generate mailer Usermailer**

Macintosh:mailtest allenroulston$ rails generate mailer Usermailer
/Users/allenroulston/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.1@rails5.0/gems/actionmailer-5.0.0/lib/action_mailer/base.rb:565:in `method_missing': undefined method `default_content_type=' for ActionMailer::Base:Class
Did you mean?  default_static_extension= (NoMethodError)

Comment: provided GitHub link

Comment: After making changes to my code, as per your examples, my code does not send emails. Very strange.

Comment: Ok give me access to github code I push the example.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/120174/discussion-between-allen-roulston-and-pradeep-sapkota).

Answer (score 0):

I believe the cause of the challenge(s) I faced in getting my application to send emails was due to an initial incorrect configuration, which when properly corrected, did not result in the application sending email as I did NOT stop and restart the rails server. Most of the time it isn't necessary to stop and restart the rails server to see changes in code take effect. Clearly it is necessary when making config changes connected to the ActionMailer.